# Moving all the read queries for a website from mysql to solr

Tags: mysql, solr

Is it worthwile to move all the read queries of a medium -traffic website from mysql to solr. 
We already use solr as the search engine for our website. We load the entire records into solr once every 24 hours and then run partial imports every 20 minutes.

Is there anything to be gained apart from faster text search ?

Comment: There are certain queries involving joins and sorts which take up a lot of time and cause a lag in mysql. May be we can de-normalize these tables and move them to solr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very tricky question, and very depends on the memory on your servers and Mysql configuration.

If u do have enough memory to hold your Mysql working set - moving to Solr will not gain any benefit for simple queries.

But in case u have a lot of joins and sorts in your queries - Solr can hold the data flat, and that will speed up your queries.

Comment: Exactly , there are certain queries involving joins and sorts which take up a lot of time and cause a lag in mysql. May be we can de-normalize these tables and move them to solr

Comment: Sure, but before doing so - verify that your mysql has all needed indexes for those queries, may be it will be easier to make mysql lookups faster than add a lot of new data to solr and maintain it's consistency.